# Disable automounting in Ubuntu

Tags: mount, ubuntu-9.04, automount

I am using Ubuntu 9.04 with xfce and it keeps wanting to automount drives that I plugin, is there a way to disable this?

Comment: People from the future might find https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189715/how-to-disable-automount-of-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-19-10 or possibly https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062719/how-do-i-disable-the-auto-mounting-of-internal-drives-in-ubuntu-or-kubuntu-18-04 useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=13692)

> Uninstalling gnome-volume-manager seems really extreme... Simply turning off GVM's automounting of hot-plugged and inserted removable media would be simpler.
>
> From the Gnome Panel, click System->Preferences->Removable Drives and Media and then uncheck the first two boxes on the storage tab. This will turn off automounting for everything not defined in /etc/fstab, and you can turn it back on if desired as easily.
>
> If you just wanted to disable automounting of certain devices you could give them their own line in /etc/fstab, making sure that the fourth field of their line include noauto so they are never automounted.

[image]

(Or)

> Run Nautilus and open Edit => Preferences > Media.
> Turn off "Browse media when inserted".

Comment: Is there a similar tool for Ubuntu 12.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

Run `gnome-volume-properties` in the terminal. Uncheck whatever you do not want mounted automatically (Storage, CDs, etc).

[image]